# How to create a line pass through text from left to right with transition?

Tags: html, css

I have already got these code:

http://jsfiddle.net/Dingzhou/brj8tnbg/

```
@-webkit-keyframes inout_webkit {
0% {
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(left, #000, #000 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
    background-size: auto 8px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: 0 50%;
}
3.3% {........
```

But the result is not 100% good because what I want is only 1 line but not multiple lines appear together...

Can someone help me to check if the code is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `background-size: auto 8px` use `background-size: 100% 8px`.